# Happens-before and volatile variable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, happens-before

Following are just three "happens-before" rules of JMM. I am not listing the other rules as my question is related to these three rules only.

- Monitor lock rule. An unlock on a monitor lock happens before every
  subsequent lock on that same monitor lock.
- Thread start rule. A call to Thread.start on a thread happens before
  every action in the started thread.
- Interruption rule. A thread calling interrupt on another thread
  happens before the interrupted thread detects the interrupt (either
  by having InterruptedException thrown, or invoking isInterrupted or
  interrupted).

**Questions**

1. **1st rule question** - Let's say two threads A and B have synchronized blocks of code. Does the first rule mean that any variable set in a synchronized block in thread A, will be visible to the code in synchronized block of thread B, even if the variable is NOT declared as volatile?
2. **2nd rule question** - Let's say a thread A starts a thread B. Does the second rule mean that any variable set in a parent thread before calling start() will be visible to thread B even if the variable is NOT declared as volatile?
3. **3rd rule question** - Let's say a thread A interrupts a thread B. Does the third rule mean that any variable set in thread A before interrupting thread B will be visible to thread B after the interrupt is detected, even if the variable is not declared as volatile?

Finally, one more question:

4. In BlockingQueue documentation, it is said,

   > Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a >thread prior to placing an object into a BlockingQueue happen-before actions >subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the BlockingQueue in >another thread.

Does this mean any variable set in a thread A before enqueuing an object in the blocking queue will be visible to thread B after dequeuing the object from the queue, even if the variable is NOT declared as volatile?

Basically through the above questions, I am trying to understand if the memory flush happens after these events such that the variables need not be declared as volatile in these cases.

Comment: 4 x "Yes". They are the same question restated four times. But forget about "memory flush" picture, it's wrong. Writes are visible, end of story.

Comment: Recommendation - 'Java Concurrency in Practice' book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1st rule question - Let's say two threads A and B have synchronized blocks of code.

Threads don't *have* code.  Threads *execute* code.

> Does the first rule mean that any variable set in a synchronized block in thread A, will be visible to the code in synchronized block of thread B, even if the variable is NOT declared as volatile?

Yes, Suppose we have:

```
private int i;
private final Object lock = new Object();

void foobar(...) {
    ...
    synchronized(lock) {
        i = ...;
    }
}

int getI() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

If thread A calls `foobar()`, and then thread B subsequently calls `getI()`, then thread B will get the new value of `i`.

But note! My example above does not include any way for you to prove which call actually happened first.  If your program depends on those calls to happen in a particular order, then it's going to need more than just a mutex:  It's going to need some means to make thread B `wait()` for thread A to perform the update.

---

> 2nd rule question - Let's say a thread A starts a thread B. Does the second rule mean that any variable set in a parent thread before calling start() will be visible to thread B even if the variable is NOT declared as volatile?

Yes, that's what it means.

> 3rd rule question...

Yes again.

> 4. ... BlockingQueue ...

Yes again.

---

> ...Through the above questions, I am trying to understand if the memory flush happens after these events such that...

Don't even think about "memory flush".  That is not part of the Java language:  If it happens, it's an implementation detail, and you don't need to worry about it unless you are *implementing* a JVM.

The only concept you need to worry about is the "happens before".

Whenever the JLS says that A *happens before* B, it means that if A happens in thread 1, and B happens in thread 2, and you can *prove* that A actually did happen before B in real-time, then any field that was updated by thread 1 before A happened will be guaranteed visible in thread 2 after B happens.